# How can I install Arch Linux on a Laptop with Intel GMA 4500 MHD?

Tags: kernel, arch-linux, system-installation, distributions

I would like to install Arch Linux on my Acer TravelMate 5735Z. Sadly, it has a Intel GMA 4500 MHD graphic card. This means, I suffer from [Kernel Bug [GM45] black screen at boot (0 backlight?)](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31522).

When I boot from the installation CD for Arch Linux 2013.10.01, I can see the menu that lets me choose to install arch/boot the installed system (Ubuntu 10.04, I think)/Power off. But when I choose to install Arch, the screen gets black.

In this [German article](http://www.linuxmintusers.de/index.php?topic=7481.0), the author seems to have found a solution for Linux Mint. But he begins with "start LiveCD in compatibility mode". As there is no such thing in the Arch Menu, I thought I had to edit the installation parameters. But when I hit tab, I get some cryptic stuff:

```
. linux boot/x86_64/vmlinuz archisobasedir=arch archisolabel=ARCH_201310 init
rd=boot/x86_64/archiso.img
```

I only have WLAN, so I can't try a network installation.

How can I install Arch Linux on this computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hit <kbd>E</kbd> at the GRUB menu. According to the bug report you linked to, the workaround is to add `i915.invert_brightness=1` to your kernel parameters. Scroll down to the `kernel` line and change it to (emphasis mine):

> linux /boot/x86_64/vmlinuz archisobasedir=arch archisolabel=ARCH_201310 initrd=boot/x86_64/archiso.img **i915.invert_brightness=1**

To make these changes permanent, edit the kernel line of `/etc/default/grub` and add `i915.invert_brightness=1` to the end:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="[EXISTING VALUES] i915.invert_brightness=1"
```

Comment: To make changes permanent, I've added this to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: @moose don't do that. To make it permanent, edit `/etc/default/grub` and add it to the end  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable. That way, it will persist if you need to run `update-grub` again. See my updated answer.